# How to reduce how much area is affected when manipulating vertices?

Tags: modeling

I want to be able to reduce the amount of green area effecting the edges when manipulating the vertices that are selected.

If someone could answer how to do that I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: That is not an "area of influence", the colored green zone is just a visual guide to show which edges are connected to the selected vertex. The only possible area of influence would be if you were using *Proportional Edit* which does not seem to be the case, and even if it were, there are no discrete entities in between that can be manipulated independently because there is no more geometry there.

Comment: So then my best option would be to create another edge in the area I want to work with?

Comment: Yes, if you need more detail add more geometry. Add a loopcut with `Ctrl`+ `R`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Was just having trouble understanding how to work with specific areas. I know that adding geometry isn't always the best idea but if the is no other way that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't decrease this area, because it's just space between **Edge Loops**.

[image: 1]

2. You can expand it by using Proportional Editing (control size by using mouse scroll).

[image: 2]

3. You can decrease it by adding **Edge Loops** around chosen area.

[image: 3]